# What does pc(eV) = 300 Br(G cm) mean?

Tags: electromagnetism, units

In the January 1983 issue of the American Journal of Physics, Edward Purcell published a one-page "Round-Number Handbook of Physics" (see e.g. http://lemeshko.blogspot.com/2008/06/one-page-round-number-handbook-of.html).  In the section on unit conversions, one line reads: "pc(eV) = 300 Br(G cm)".  Does anyone have any idea what this means?  I note that 1 eV/(G cm) seems to be closely related to the elementary charge, but I still can't quite figure out what this line is about.

Answer (score 0):

It's the [cyclotron radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroradius) $r$ for a particle with momentum $p$ in a magnetic field $B$,

$$
|q|Br = p_\perp,
$$

for the common case where the particle has one quantum of charge.

The numerical conversion constant 300 has the same first significant figure as the speed of light, $c = \rm 3\times10^8\,m/s$. The "rule of thumb" multiplies both sides by $c$ so that both have energy units --- the [electron-volt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_volt) is a convenient unit of energy for subatomic particles. The numerical factor ends up as $3\times 10^2$ because of the difference between gauss-centimeters and the SI unit, tesla-meters.

Comment: Yes, this looks right, thanks so much.  Specifically, it appears to be the cyclotron radius for a particle of charge $e$.

Comment: If you find the answer useful, you might consider clicking the "upvote" or "accept" buttons. Glad to have you here at [physics.se]!